# GroupBy two variables, one of them is from a nested list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, group-by

I have a problem with grouping items by two variables (in this case: Item.Name and Category.CategoryId) One of them is from a nested list.

Grouping with my code works doesn't seem to work well.
Also if it's possible I want to have a Dictionary as a result.

I'm trying to achieve something like this :

```
Name "1", CategoryId "2" 
Name "1", CategoryId "2"

-----------------------

Name "1", CategoryId "3"

-----------------------

Name "2", CategoryId "2"
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<GroupingStruct, List<Item>> result;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
                {
                    new Item { Name = "Name 1"},
                    new Item { Name = "Name 1"},
                    new Item { Name = "Name 1"},
                    new Item { Name = "Name 2"},
                };

            items[0].Categories.Add(new Category { CategoryId = "Category Id 2", Value = 1 });
            items[0].Categories.Add(new Category { CategoryId = "Category Id 3", Value = 5 });
            items[1].Categories.Add(new Category { CategoryId = "Category Id 2", Value = 7 });
            items[2].Categories.Add(new Category { CategoryId = "Category Id 2", Value = 9 });

            result = items.SelectMany(i => i.Categories.Select(x => new { It = i, Cat = x }))
                .GroupBy(g => new GroupingStruct()
                {
                    ItemName = g.It.Name,
                    CategoryId = g.Cat.CategoryId,
                })
                .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(x => x.It).ToList());
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
        public Guid Guid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public struct GroupingStruct
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there some reason you need `GroupingStruct`? An anonymous type implements equality properly for you (e.g. `GroupBy(i => new { i.It.Name, i.Cat.CategoryId })`). If you need cross module access, consider using a `ValueTuple`: `GroupBy(i => (i.It.Name, i.Cat.CategoryId))`.

Comment: GroupingStruct was just my final form of trying. I've already overwritten GetHashCode and added Equal Method. But I don't think it's my main problem here.

Answer (score 0):

`.GroupBy()` requires `GroupingStruct` to implement `Equals` method from `IEquatable<GroupingStruct>` interface as it is a part of **LINQ**. You also should override `object.GetHashCode` and 'object.Equals' for consistency. **LINQ** and **Collections** usually use these methods for equality.

```cs
public struct GroupingStruct: IEquatable<GroupingStruct> {
  public string ItemName {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string CategoryId {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public bool Equals(GroupingStruct other) {
    return ItemName == other.ItemName && CategoryId == other.CategoryId;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
     if (!(obj is GroupingStruct))
     return false;

     return Equals((GroupingStruct) obj);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return string.Format("{0}{1}", ItemName, CategoryId).GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes maybe it's a turn into good direction, but after implementing your changes the results are the same, grouping doesn't work well. Also I used struct because with class my code has less sense, so don't know if GetHashCode have sens also here ?

Comment: @YorbGG `GroupBy` uses both of these methods. You can check by setting breakpoints or printing something on Console.

Comment: @YorbGG My bad, I guess I should override `object.Equals` for Dictionary.

Comment: I see now. Still its wierd to me, Equals returned 'true' 2 times but still I have 3 items in one group and 1 in second group. Should be then 3 groups, because we have two matches, no two differences. Also I think using object.Equals is wrong here, we need to copare strings/struct, no references ?

Comment: @YorbGG `GroupBy` use mostly `GetHashCode`. If hashes are the same, then `IEquatable.Equals` is called.

Comment: @YorbGG Ok, Actually Item "Name 2" has no category added. You need to access the item via `items[3]`

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong, so once again. So far it's grouping like this : for Key 'Category Id 2' and 'Name1', it puts it with 'Category Id 3' and 'Name 1'. But it should Group like e.g your Equal. Category and Name should be the same, if not then it should make a new pair in Dictionary.

Comment: Ok,  Key 'Category Id 2' and 'Name1' has 3 elements with values 1,7,9 and Key Category Id 3' and 'Name 1' with the only element with value 5. When I run this code I get results like that. I think we get adequate outcome out of the code.

Comment: Yes I have the same result. But we are grouping by Name and CategoryId, so variable Value is no important here, anyway regardless of my code or results I want to improve code to achieve grouping like in my example (3 pairs in Dictionary)

Comment: @YorbGG You can't have 3 pairs in Dictionary since you use `SelectMany` so the first item has 2 categories and is added twice in the dictionary.

Comment: So how to avoid that ? Just not using a 'SelectMany' ? If so,  how to write a proper code without it ?

Comment: @YorbGG Everything depends on what you want. While you want to group by Item's name and category's id, you don't consider  Item has many categories. So you need to rethink if this is a proper way or just choose one category by the desired condition. For example, rewrite `items.SelectMany(i => i.Categories.Select(x => new { It = i, Cat = x }))` to `items.Select(i => i.Categories.Last(x => new { It = i, Cat = x }))`.

Comment: I also don't see a easy way to grouping it by Item.Name and Category.Id if on item has many categories at the same time, because I want to have this item in as many pairs (in the result Dictionary) as many it has categories - so it should be copied if needed but put with different Keys.

Comment: Looks like you already found an answer then here. I think you don't even need  `GroupingStruct`. You can use anonymous objects instead like the other guy commented here. C# compares corresponding properties in order to determine equality.

Answer (score 0):

Using an anonymous type for the key will allow `GroupBy` to match on all members, and then you can select out the items.

```
var result = items
    .SelectMany(i => i.Categories.Select(c => new { Key = new { i.Name, c.CategoryId }, Item = i }))
    .GroupBy(ki => ki.Key)
    .ToDictionary(ki => ki.Key, ki => ki.Select(x => x.Item).ToList());
```

If you need to use the `Dictionary` outside the method where you create `result`, you can replace the anonymous type with `ValueTuple`:

```
var result = items
    .SelectMany(i => i.Categories.Select(c => new { Key = (i.Name, c.CategoryId), Item = i }))
    .GroupBy(ki => ki.Key)
    .ToDictionary(ki => ki.Key, ki => ki.Select(x => x.Item).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesn't work as I want. For example, for Key 'Name 1' and CategoryId '2' it returns Item (Values) with 'Name 1' CategoryId '2' (it's ok) but also Category '3' - so it's wrong. It should only return 'Name 1' CategoryId '2', and 'Name 1' and Category '3' as a new pair.

Comment: @YorbGG What do you mean by "returns"? `Name 1` is in both `Category 2` and `Category 3` so it is included with each key. The object named `Name 1` has both `Category 2` and `Category 3` in its list of `Categories` so `Category 3` shows up under key `Category 2`. Since `Name 1` has both categories, it will show up twice, it is the _same object_. You said nothing about creating new objects.

Comment: By 'returns' I mean what is in the end in the result dictionary.

Comment: @YorbGG Your sample code does not add any categories to "Name 2" so it is not included in the output. Can you fix your code or expected output to match?